# Function decomposition in sympy

Tags: python, math, sympy

I am trying to figure out how to do function decomposition in SymPy

I can do function composition in SymPy:

```
from sympy import symbols, cos, sin, diff

x = symbols('x')
h = cos(x)
g = sin(h)

g
```

> sin(cos(x))

And SymPy is able to differentiate this

```
diff(g)
```

> -sin(x)*cos(cos(x))

**But how do I break `sin(cos(x))` into `f(x)=sin(x)` and `g(x)=cos(x)`?** It seems like it must do this internally so even if this isn't part of the api, it would be helpful to find where it does this internally. I looked at the source and I just see it applying the quotient rule rather than the chain rule so I may be looking in the wrong place:

[def diff in the repo](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/f52535c20f7d4af378b22d51222e725e18c883d3/sympy/polys/fields.py#L565):

```
def diff(f, x):
    """Computes partial derivative in ``x``.
    Examples
    ========
    >>> from sympy.polys.fields import field
    >>> from sympy.polys.domains import ZZ
    >>> _, x, y, z = field("x,y,z", ZZ)
    >>> ((x**2 + y)/(z + 1)).diff(x)
    2*x/(z + 1)
    """
    x = x.to_poly()
    return f.new(f.numer.diff(x)*f.denom - f.numer*f.denom.diff(x), f.denom**2)
```

I have trouble telling where `f.numer.diff` leads. [This code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/6369b9d8a03659216dcf80ff083921464b160d69/sympy/vector/basisdependent.py) may be it but I'm not sure and I don't know how to identify where in that code it has what I'm looking for.

What I'm looking for is to give it something like (to use a different example to show the variety of things I'm looking for) `(2x)^5` and get `2x` and `x^5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To break a composition into pieces, use two fundamental properties of a SymPy expression: [func (the "outer" function) and args (its arguments)](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#recursing-through-an-expression-tree).

```
expr = sin(cos(x))
print(expr.func, expr.args)   # prints sin and (cos(x), )
print(expr.func(x))   #  sin(x)
print(expr.args[0])   #  cos(x)
```

By the way, the chain rule logic is in the internal [`_eval_derivative`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/f52535c20f7d4af378b22d51222e725e18c883d3/sympy/core/function.py#L558) method of the Function class. This is where the evaluation of the derivative of `f(g(x))` eventually leads. You were looking at the Polys class.

The general dispatching of derivative of all kinds of objects is in [`Derivative.__new_`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/function.py#L1102).